# Why doesn't parskip=half work together with fontenc in bibliographies?

Tags: biblatex, koma-script, incompatibility, font-encodings, parskip

If `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` is used and `parskip=half` is set:

[image: incorrect output]

Else (either `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` isn't used or `parskip=half` isn't set):

[image: correct output]

I consider the second one the correct style. Why is there a problem when using `parskip`? And more importantly, why does `fontenc` influence anything here?

```
\documentclass[
    parskip=half
]{scrbook}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{biblatextest.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A. and Buthor, B.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha Alpha Alpha Alpha Alpha Alpha Alpha Alpha Alpha Alpha Alpha Alpha Alpha Alpha Alpha Alpha Alpha Alpha Alpha Alpha },
}
@misc{A02,
  author = {Authora, A. and Buthora, B.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Beta Beta Beta Beta Beta Beta Beta Beta Beta Beta Beta Beta Beta Beta Beta Beta },
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{biblatextest.bib}

\begin{document}

Some text \cite{A01}. More... \cite{A02}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

With `biblatex`, the hanging indentation of bibliographies is controlled by the `\bibhang` length which is initialized to the value of `\parindent` at the time `biblatex` is loaded. As a matter of principle, the class option `parskip=half` sets `\parindent` to 0pt, so `\bibhang`  becomes 0pt, too. The remedy is either to set the `parskip=half` option after loading `biblatex` (using `\KOMAoptions`) or to manually set `\bibhang` to a suitable value.

Why does `fontenc` matter? Actually, the settings of the `parskip` option go in effect only after `\selectfont` has been issued. Without `fontenc`, the implicit issuing of `\normalsize` at the start of the document body will call `\selectfont`, but `fontenc` features its own `\selectfont` call.

Comment: So, can this be considered a `biblatex` bug? After all, those are not paragraphs in the bibliography.

Comment: @neo It's at least an unfortunate feature.

Comment: By the way, I opened a bug ticket a while ago and this will be fixed in the next biblatex version: https://sourceforge.net/p/biblatex/bugs/172/

Answer (score 6):

I do not exactly know why it happens but I have a workaround:

Use `\KOMAoption{parskip}{half}` instead of the class option `parskip=half` and it works for me (MiKTeX 2.9).

Test it with the following, a little bit changed MWE:

```
%http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/76029/why-doesnt-parskip-half-work-together-with-fontenc-in-bibliographies
\documentclass[%
  paper=a4
%,parskip=half
]{scrbook}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage[style=authoryear,natbib]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A. and Buthor, B.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha Alpha Alpha Alpha Alpha Alpha Alpha Alpha Alpha Alpha Alpha Alpha Alpha Alpha Alpha Alpha Alpha Alpha Alpha Alpha },
}
@misc{A02,
  author = {Authora, A. and Buthora, B.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Beta Beta Beta Beta Beta Beta Beta Beta Beta Beta Beta Beta Beta Beta Beta Beta },
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\KOMAoption{parskip}{half}
%\KOMAoptions{parskip=half}

Some text \cite{A01}. More... \cite{A02}. More text. More text. More text. More text. More text. 
More text. More text. More text. More text. More text. More text. More text. More text. More text. 

More text. More text. More text. More text. More text. More text. More text. More text. More text. 
More text. More text. More text. More text. More text. More text. More text. More text. More text. 
More text. More text. More text. More text. More text. More text. More text. More text. More text. 

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```